# How can I get all the radio buttons in each group and check one is checked in each group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radio-group

Range of radio buttons in a form. jQuery check that a radio is selected for each group and add a class to the label associated if not.

I have checked and the name of the group is correctly added to the variable 'radio'. Any ideas?

```
$('.checkbox', this).each(function()
{
    var radio = $(this).attr("name");
    if ($('input[name='+ radio +']:checked').length) 
    {
        $('label[for=' + radio + ']').addClass('error_label');
        required = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        $('label[for=' + radio + ']').removeClass('error_label');
    }
});
```

Comment: You're adding the `error_label` class when one of the radio buttons is checked, not the other way around as your question seems to imply.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GFCKA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more efficient approach. Also, you might not want to add 'error' class to all the radio button labels within a group.

[Please check this](http://jsfiddle.net/kjxuA/1/)

=== Updated to include the code in the answer ===

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio-group">
    <h3>Group 1</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="group_1" id="opt1" value="1" />
    <label for="opt1">Option 1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group_1" id="opt2" value="2" />
    <label for="opt2">Option 2</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group_1" id="opt3" value="3" />
    <label for="opt3">Option 3</label>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="radio-group">
    <h3>Group 2</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="group_2" id="opt4" value="1" />
    <label for="opt4">Option 1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group_2" id="opt5" value="2" />
    <label for="opt5">Option 2</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group_2" id="opt6" value="3" />
    <label for="opt6">Option 3</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-group">
    <h3>Group 3</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="group_3" id="opt8" value="1" />
    <label for="opt8">Option 1</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group_3" id="opt9" value="2" />
    <label for="opt9">Option 2</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group_3" id="opt10" value="3" />
    <label for="opt10">Option 3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $(".radio-group").each(function(){
            if($(this).find("input:radio:checked").length) {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("error");
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: use `removeClass()` when the missing radio is checked would help also so user see's that all arrors clear before they try submit again

Comment: Fiddles are fine, but please also post the code in your answer. Stack Overflow aims to be self-contained, and it's difficult to discuss code that is not actually here (e.g. @charlietfl's comment above has no visible context to build upon).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Will be mindful of that. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check like this when adding the class:

```
if ($('input[name=' + radio + ']:radio:checked').length == 0) {
    // Add class...
}
```

Comment: Note that proper escaping needs to be applied